# Debug custom XAML Converter

Tags: c#, xaml, debugging, uwp

maybe a dumb question. I'm facing a problem with my BoolVisibilityConverter because my Value pulled to the converter is always: false... sometimes true, but i can't debug through the binding, to which object is bound to the parent object.

Here are my snippets:
Converter class:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null || (bool)value == false)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value != null && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

XAML declaration for my converter:

```
<converter:FalseVisiblityConverter x:Key="FalseVisibilityConverter" />
```

XAML outline for a button:

```
<Button Tag="delete" Click="EntryActionButton" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Visibility="{x:Bind IsNew, Converter={StaticResource FalseVisibilityConverter}}">
    <Viewbox MaxHeight="13" MaxWidth="13">
        <Grid>
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

So... is there a way to properly debug such converter, if i'm jumping out the converter Visual Studio want's to jump in Modul Windows.UI.Xaml.dll which is useless to me, since I still don't have any clue what exact object is handled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Maybe the reason is that you're using `x:bind` of which the default mode is `OneTime`. So when your `View` gets loaded for the fist time, the `boolean` property is `false` and then later when the data gets loaded into your `boolean`, since it's a `OneTime binding`, the view does not check for `PropertyChanged` event. Add a `Mode=OneWay` as part of your `Visibility Binding`. Your updated code would look like:

```
<Button Tag="delete" Click="EntryActionButton" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Visibility="{x:Bind IsNew, Converter={StaticResource FalseVisibilityConverter, Mode=OneWay}}">
    <Viewbox MaxHeight="13" MaxWidth="13">
        <Grid>
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Another alternate would be to use `Binding` instead of `x:bind` but I'd say, add the `Mode=OneWay`. I just wanted to add this for completeness of the answer.

### Other ways to debug converter malfunctioning

- Add a breakpoint in the `Convert` method and see how many times does it trigger? Does it trigger when the value changes?

Below is a `BoolToInverseVisibilityConverter` that I generally use for `OneWay` bindings. I don't implement the `ConvertBack` because it's only called in `TwoWay` bindings:

```
public class BoolToInverseVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is bool booleanValue && booleanValue)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for my late response! you're right, default is OneTime, in My Case that shouldn't matter, because the Object is completely initialized before rendering the xaml... I had another logical error in my object model -.- an later on, i stuck on the problem, that my IsNew property wasn't implemented completely in my PropertyChanged! So.. yeah, my initial question wasn't answered but thanks for pulling in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

@iam.Carrot 's answer is correct. In addition to his answer, I have one thing that I'd like to say.

Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, the XAML framework provides **a built in boolean to Visibility converter**. The converter maps `true` to the `Visible` enumeration value and `false` to `Collapsed` so you can bind a Visibility property to a boolean without creating a converter. To use the built in converter, your app's **minimum target SDK** version must be **14393 or later**. You can't use it when your app targets earlier versions of Windows 10.

So you could directly bind the value like this:

```
<Button Tag="delete" Click="EntryActionButton" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Visibility="{x:Bind IsNew,Mode=OneWay}">
```

Comment: I didn't know about the built-in bool to visibility converter. Thanks for pointing it out. Although the OP is using a bool to inverse visibility, meaning `Collapsed` when `True` and `Visible` when `False`. Now I know we can always make another property to bind to, but I was just curious if this is also built-in?

Comment: @iam.Carrot I did not understand `we can always make another property to bind to` well, do you mean using bool to bind to visibility?

Comment: What I meant was since the OP wanted the clause `if IsNew then Visibility.Collapsed else Visibility.Visible" instead of using a Bool to inverse visibility converter we can create a new property called `IsNotNew` and then use the built in Bool to visibility converter. But the question I wanted to ask was is there a built in converter for bool to inverse visibility?

Comment: @iam.Carrot I got your point. But the answer is no. Currently, there is no build-in Bool to inverse visibility converter. The way you did to create an inverse converter is the correct way.

Comment: you're correct. There is, but as @iam.Carrot pointed out, i hat to negate the boolean :) and meanwhile i have a proper Converter class, which i use in several projects i mentaly stuck on my own ones :)